# Going from a Storyboard to Nib and back again

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, segue, nib

Ok, I'm still pretty new; so, please bear with me.

I'm creating a custom app for a friend that displays a list of work orders in a table view. Clicking on a work order brings them to a detail view. In the detail view, there is a button that uses a push to present another screen called completion view. From the completion view, they click a button that uses the following code to present a nib for signature capture.

```
SigScreenViewController *sigScreenViewController=[[SigScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

[self presentViewController:sigScreenViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The signature screen uses: https://github.com/jcmontiel/SignatureViewExample for capturing the signature and does it well. I have a button that completes the transaction and sends it back to the table view list.

My problem is that I cannot create a button that will return me to the completion view in the storyboard.

I've tried the following in a button:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

or

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I'm open for any suggestions on how I can do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean on completion view, clicking on back/done button doesn't bring you back to the previous viewController? Did you check if your UIButton handler is getting called on tap. Is it properly linked in storyboard with its handler and property.

Comment: Sounds like a cool app. Are you saying you can't dismiss the signature view? Did you put this code in the signature view controller: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];  That code should work.

Comment: I can dismiss the signature view and it will go back to the table view and perform that code fine when signing. I need a button that will leave the signature view should they forget to add something like a part to the work order (completion view).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried having the UIViewControllers embedded in a navigation controller ?

Are you pushing from a UIViewController in UIStoryboard to a NIB file?

If so check out this [sample project](https://github.com/LuAndreCast/ObjectiveC_Projects/tree/master/scrollView/scrollViewFromStoryBoard_And_XIB_File) that pushes from storyboard to a NIB:

```
// in a navigation controller

// to load/push to new controller use this code

// this will be next screen
DetailsViewController *detailsViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc ]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];


// to go back or pop controller use this
// now it will send back to parent screen
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```